# Automatic hide submit button in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
 I want to hide my submit button without mouse click & show message.
```

when main balance less then form input withdraw amount. 
Then automatic hide submit button and show message that `insufficient balance`

Html Code:

```
  <div id="message"></div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <center><button type="submit" id="withdraw_button" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded w-md waves-effect waves-light m-b-5">Withdraw</button></center>
                    </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var main_balance  = $("#main_balance").val();

$('#withdraw_amount').blur(function(){
var input_amount = $(this).val();
if (input_amount.length != 0) {
  if (input_amount > main_balance) {

      // When insinuation balance then hide button automatic

       $('#withdraw_button').hidden();

       // Show message 
       // how can i see it

    }    
   }
  });
 });
```

How can solve this problem. current i use *laravel framework*.

Comment: `.hide()` not `.hidden()` and if the values is a string you'll need to use  `parseInt()` to make it integer

Comment: you can add show() and hide() another way is you can add hide class of bootstrap and remove it using addClass() and removeClass()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you looking for that.**
i basically set your main balance to 20 and if input greater than 20, than submit button will hide. also you can add message in if or else condition as per your requeirements.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var main_balance  = 20;

$('#withdraw_amount').keyup(function(){
var input_amount = $(this).val();
if (input_amount.length != 0) {
  if (input_amount > main_balance) {

      // When insinuation balance then hide button automatic

       $('#withdraw_button').hide();

       // Show message 
        $('#message').html('insufficient balance');
       // how can i see it

    } else {
     $('#withdraw_button').show();
     $('#message').html('');
     }
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="number" name="withdraw_amount" id="withdraw_amount">
      <center><button type="submit" id="withdraw_button" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded w-md waves-effect waves-light m-b-5">Withdraw</button></center>
                    </div>
```

Comment: How can i show message `Insinuation Your balance`  <div id="message"></div>

Comment: see now. for message

Answer (score 1):

try adding `else` in your function:

```
if (input_amount > main_balance) {
   //When insinuation balance then hide button automatic
   $('#withdraw_button').hide();
   alert('Insufficient balance!');
}else{
    $('#withdraw_button').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update your jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var main_balance  = $("#main_balance").val();

$('#withdraw_amount').blur(function(){
var input_amount = $(this).val();
if (input_amount.length != 0) {
  if (input_amount > main_balance) {

      // When insinuation balance then hide button automatic

       $('#withdraw_button').hide();

       // Show message 
       // how can i see it

    } else {
        $('#withdraw_button').show();
    }
   }
  });
    $('body').click(function(){

      $('#withdraw_button').hide();
    });
 });
```

Comment: how can slove this

Comment: @HasanSheikh the `.blur` means you need to click outside .. to get the realtime action you need to change `.blur(function` to `.on('input' , function`

Answer (score 0):

Bind multiple events to avoid click outside to fire event.

```
$("#withdraw_amount").bind("keyup change", function(e)
```

here is your modified code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var main_balance  = Number($("#main_balance").val());

    //$('#withdraw_amount').keyup(function(){
    $("#withdraw_amount").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
        var input_amount = Number($(this).val());
        if (input_amount.length != 0) {
            if (input_amount > main_balance) {
              // When insinuation balance then hide button automatic
               $('#withdraw_button').hide();
               $('#message').text("insufficient balance");
               // Show message 
               // how can i see it
           } else {
                $('#message').text("");
                $('#withdraw_button').show();
           }   
        }
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7psw36ro/)